# Unexpected 1px-2px "margin" appears between parent and child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a navigation bar which is a red `div`, containing two `ul`, on left and right side respectively. Margins and paddings of both parent and children are declared 0 but there are still 1px-2px red gaps appeared around the two children.

I have checked the Developer Tools, heights of children match the parent `div`. I don't know why top and bottom gaps can still exist. In addition, red gap does also appear on the left to the left `ul` and right to the right `ul`.

The existence of gaps is dependent to the screen size. While I control the width of Developer Tools, they keep appearing and disappearing respectively. Perhaps it's issue of the browser? I'm using Chrome. How to solve this?

Here is the code

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 896px) {
  html {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  html {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  html {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1152px) {
  html {
    font-size: 21px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  html {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  html {
    font-size: 23px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  html {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity: 0.95;
    border: 15px ridge;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-collapse: separate!important;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0!important;
  border: 5px outset;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.navbar-left {
  float: left;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}

.myName {
    background-color: #666666;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar ul li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

.navbar ul li a.active {background-color: #4bf5c9;}

.navbar ul li a.active:hover {background-color: #32a386;}

.navbar ul li.right {float: right;}

.icon {
    height: 1rem;
    margin: auto 10px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-left">
            <li><a class="active" href="menu.aspx">Menu</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a class="myName"><img src="img/user-24.ico" class="icon" />Usernme</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="login.aspx"><img src="img/logout-24.ico" class="icon" />Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Here is a screenshot for the part]

Comment: I don't see any red gap. Can you share a working demo for the problem. You can use the [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve] - you can get images from placeholder.com - since there are no gaps in the snippet, I assume the images push something

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Btw a screenshot has been added. I wish it can better illustrate the problem.

Comment: The snippet does not look at all like your image

Comment: You can try making the .navbar flex with justify-content space-between and align-items stretch, instead of using float.

Comment: You may be coming up against the browser having problems with mapping part pixels (CSS pixels and screen pixels are not the same on hi def displays). Please put up a snippet which demonstrates the problem. And is it at only certain zoom levels?

Comment: @mplungjan edited the code. It matches the screenshot now, though the red gaps do not appear in the snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)